# Comparison between @kriskowal's "Q" library and @forbeslindesay's "Promise" library

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I am looking to find the significant difference between "Q" and "Promise" libraries as both are to deal with promises to handle asynchronous callbacks conveniently. I got confused in which one is better.

Comment: forbeslindesay's promise library is barebones Promise/A+ - Q adds sugar to make common "patterns" far easier to code - if you want extra sugar and faster promises, use bluebird

Answer (score 0):

You don't *really* need either in Node as it supports [native promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)s.